# Deixando o Fullcalendar no idioma pt-BR

Tags: javascript, jquery, data, fullcalendar

Olá, eu baixei um template **fullcalendar** do *Adan Shaw*, só que a linguagem padrão é inglês, gostaria de deixá-lo em português.
Como realizo essa mudança?
Obrigado.

Comment: Olá @ThiagoFerreira seja bem vindo ao StackOverflow. Tem algum código onde podemos nos basear para a solução do seu problema?

Answer (score 14):

Dentro da pasta que você baixou do fullcalendar, tem a subpasta lang que contém todas as linguagens suportadas pelo fullcalendar
[image: pasta 1]
[image: pasta 2]
Copie o javascript `pt-br.js` e inclua no seu projeto.

Seu cabeçalho ficaria assim:

```
<script src='fullcalendar/fullcalendar.js'></script>
<script src='fullcalendar/lang/pt-br.js'></script>
<script>

    $(document).ready(function() {

        $('#calendar').fullCalendar({
            //toda chamada de texto do fullcalendar será buscada do arquivo pt-br.js
        });

    });

</script>
```

Aqui tem a [Documentação oficial](http://fullcalendar.io/docs/text/lang/) que possa te ajudar.

Comment: Gustavo essa seria minha resposta, porém, para uma resposta mais completa adicione a maneira de adicionar no projeto de preferência com exemplos. Fica mais fácil para o AP entender e uma resposta completa irá te render mais pontos. ;)

Comment: É, pega esse js e joga aonde, na documentação não fala onde certo.

Comment: Ok @Pedro, editado! No caso Thiago, você deve incluir os .js dentro do path do seu projeto e incluir pelo <script src='seu_path/pt-br.js'></script>

Comment: O pt-br já está no meu projeto, como todas as linguagens, eu consigo visualizar o arquivo .js no meu projeto na pasta lang. Só que eu não estou usando ele. Eu não consegui localizar esse cabeçalho Gustavo.

Comment: Esse script vai no arquivo fullcalendar.css ?

Comment: Esse script vai na sua página que será exibido o calendário. Como você fez o fullcalendar funcionar? Será da mesma forma para fazer o outro js funcionar.

Comment: Então Gustavo, pelo código descrito acima, creio que vai ser em algum .css, deduzo isso por causa da tag <script>

Comment: Pretendo marcar uma resposta, ninguém???

Comment: +1. Funcionou pra mim.

Answer (score 12):

Tente mudar as configurações do seu FullCalendar assim:

```
calendar = $('#calendar').fullCalendar({
    ignoreTimezone: false,
    monthNames: ['Janeiro', 'Fevereiro', 'Março', 'Abril', 'Maio', 'Junho', 'Julho', 'Agosto', 'Setembro', 'Outubro', 'Novembro', 'Dezembro'],
    monthNamesShort: ['Jan', 'Fev', 'Mar', 'Abr', 'Mai', 'Jun', 'Jul', 'Ago', 'Set', 'Out', 'Nov', 'Dez'],
    dayNames: ['Domingo', 'Segunda', 'Terça', 'Quarta', 'Quinta', 'Sexta', 'Sabado'],
    dayNamesShort: ['Dom', 'Seg', 'Ter', 'Qua', 'Qui', 'Sex', 'Sab'],
    titleFormat: {
        month: 'MMMM yyyy',
        week: "d[ MMMM][ yyyy]{ - d MMMM yyyy}",
        day: 'dddd, d MMMM yyyy'
    },
    columnFormat: {
        month: 'ddd',
        week: 'ddd d',
        day: ''
    },
    axisFormat: 'H:mm',
    timeFormat: {
        '': 'H:mm',
        agenda: 'H:mm{ - H:mm}'
    },
    buttonText: {
        prev: "&nbsp;&#9668;&nbsp;",
        next: "&nbsp;&#9658;&nbsp;",
        prevYear: "&nbsp;&lt;&lt;&nbsp;",
        nextYear: "&nbsp;&gt;&gt;&nbsp;",
        today: "Hoje",
        month: "Mês",
        week: "Semana",
        day: "Dia"
    }
});
```

Comment: Oloco na mão, não seria trocar o 'en' por 'pt-br' apenas?

Comment: E se você quiser algo customizado ou até mesmo não tiver o referenciamento "pt-br". Você vai ter que baixar esse arquivo da mesma forma. Isso aí eu explico como funciona a tradução do FullCalendar. ;)

Answer (score 1):

É possível setar a propriedade `locale` para `pt-br`.

Porém, mesmo alterando o `locale`, precisei setar outras propriedades manualmente, como `timeFormat`, `buttonText`, entre outras.

Confira minhas configurações atuais:

```
this.calendarOptions = {
      locale: 'pt-br',
      timeFormat: 'HH:mm',
      editable: true,
      eventLimit: false,
      displayEventTime: this.displayEventTime,
      slotLabelFormat: 'HH:mm',
      allDayText: '24 horas',
      columnFormat: 'dddd',
      header: {
        left: 'prev,next today',
        center: 'title',
        right: 'month,agendaWeek,agendaDay,listMonth'
      },
      buttonText: {
        today: 'Hoje',
        month: 'Mês',
        week: 'Semana',
        day: 'Hoje',
        list: 'Lista'
      },
      events: this.eventsCalendar
    };
```

Documentação com mais detalhes sobre o 'locale': https://fullcalendar.io/docs/locale